Overriding template name in Django
I'm sorry, I can't understand why template_name won't override default value. It was my understanding that it combines the app name with the model or view name to form the template filename, unless overriden by template_name:
class TaskList(ListView):
    model = Task
    template_name='test.html'
    context_object_name='tasks'

It still shows the default template (task_list), despite I've tried to override it.
I tried clearing cache (by deleting pychache folder), but it didn't work.
Thank you for any suggestions!

What name is in your url.py file?

What is the path to the test.html template file ?
